# Sum after Averaging in MYSQL Query

Tags: mysql, sum, average

I have a trouble when I am trying to Avarege a column and then I want to SUM the result, I am using MYSQL to do that. Can anyone help me? Here is the query that isn't work :

```
SUM(IF(AVG(Value)=3,1,0)) AS green
```

Full Query :

```
SELECT
  cluster,
  SUM(IF(AVG(Value) AS Value = 3,1,0)) AS green
FROM network
WHERE date>= '2012-07-01'
    AND date<= '2012-07-02'
    AND Region = 'SOMEREG'
    AND cluster IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY cluster
```

Comment: can you post table structure along with full query and details of group by clause?

Comment: I've update the query and I'll wait the answer ;)

Comment: it seems that you want to show count or sum of values if avg(value) = 3. Am i right?

Answer (score 0):

```
That should not be an if, but a where in the select statement.

SELECT cluster,
SUM(Value) AS sumValue AVG(Value) AS avgValue
FROM network
WHERE date>= '2012-07-01'
AND date<= '2012-07-02'
AND Region = 'SOMEREG'
AND ((AVG(Value) = 3) OR (AVG(Value) = 1) OR (AVG(Value) = 0))
AND cluster IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY cluster
```

Comment: @George Aguirre: Did you try the query yourself first??

Comment: The truth query is :
SELECT
  cluster,
  SUM(IF(AVG(Value)=3,1,0)) AS green,
  SUM(IF(AVG(Value)=2,1,0)) AS yellow,
  SUM(IF(AVG(Value)=1,1,0)) AS red,
FROM table
WHERE date>= '2012-07-01'
    AND date<= '2012-07-02'
    AND Region= 'SOMEREG'
    AND cluster IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY cluster

Can you make it clear please?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply only one aggregate function at a time.

Multiple aggregate functions for same group by clause does not make sense. 
You need create derived table to find the sum of average. try:

```
SELECT SUM(green) AS green
FROM (
      SELECT cluster,
             IF(AVG(Value) = 3, 1, 0) AS green
      FROM network
      WHERE date BETWEEN '2012-07-01' AND '2012-07-02'
            AND Region = 'SOMEREG'
            AND cluster IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY cluster
     ) a;
```

Comment: so, how can I SUM the AVERAGE result? Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

simply do this

```
SELECT
  IFNULL(cluster,'Total'),
  SUM(IF(AVG(Value) AS Value = 3,1,0)) AS green
FROM network
WHERE date>= '2012-07-01'
    AND date<= '2012-07-02'
    AND Region = 'SOMEREG'
    AND cluster IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY cluster with roll up
```

Add roll up it will add all averages